# WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.と出ますが、解決法をご教授願ます。

Tags: linux, debian

夜分遅くに失礼いたします。お世話になります。

Debian 10にActivityWatchというManicTimeのようなOSSのインストールを行っておりますが、
インストールをしたあとに`aw-qt`を実行しますと、下記のWARNINGが出ます。
`WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.`

bashの履歴は下記となります。

```sh
~/activitywatch$ aw-qt
2019-12-06 23:38:40 [INFO ]: Starting module aw-server  (aw_qt.manager:49)
2019-12-06 23:38:40 [INFO ]: Trying to start aw-server using PATH (executable not found in: ['/home/yusuke/activitywatch/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aw_qt/aw-server', '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aw-server', '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aw-server/aw-server'])  (aw_qt.manager:36)
2019-12-06 23:38:40 [INFO ]: Starting module aw-watcher-afk  (aw_qt.manager:49)
2019-12-06 23:38:40 [INFO ]: Trying to start aw-watcher-afk using PATH (executable not found in: ['/home/yusuke/activitywatch/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aw_qt/aw-watcher-afk', '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aw-watcher-afk', '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aw-watcher-afk/aw-watcher-afk'])  (aw_qt.manager:36)
2019-12-06 23:38:40 [INFO ]: Starting module aw-watcher-window  (aw_qt.manager:49)
2019-12-06 23:38:40 [INFO ]: Trying to start aw-watcher-window using PATH (executable not found in: ['/home/yusuke/activitywatch/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aw_qt/aw-watcher-window', '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aw-watcher-window', '/home/yusuke/activitywatch/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aw-watcher-window/aw-watcher-window'])  (aw_qt.manager:36)
2019-12-06 23:38:40 [INFO ]: Creating trayicon...  (aw_qt.trayicon:150)
2019-12-06 23:38:40 [INFO ]: aw-watcher-afk started  (aw_watcher_afk.afk:53)
2019-12-06 23:38:40 [INFO ]: aw-watcher-window started  (aw_watcher_window.main:42)
2019-12-06 23:38:41 [INFO ]: Using storage method: peewee  (aw_server.main:26)
2019-12-06 23:38:41 [INFO ]: Starting up...  (aw_server.main:31)
2019-12-06 23:38:41 [INFO ]: Using database file: /home/yusuke/.local/share/activitywatch/aw-server/peewee-sqlite.v2.db  (aw_datastore.storages.peewee:90)
 * Serving Flask app "aw-server" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
2019-12-06 23:38:41 [INFO ]:  * Running on http://localhost:5600/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)  (werkzeug:122)
2019-12-06 23:38:41 [INFO ]: Connection to aw-server established by aw-watcher-afk  (aw_client.client:348)
2019-12-06 23:38:41 [INFO ]: Connection to aw-server established by aw-watcher-window  (aw_client.client:348)
```

WARNINGが出ない方法をご教授願ます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
>     Use a production WSGI server instead.

動かすだけなら、ワーニングは無視していいと思います。
試してませんが、ワーニングを消すには gunicorn などの WSGI サーバーを使えばいいと思います。

Python に組み込まれた Web サーバー機能は、機能的に貧弱で、セキュリティ対策も行われてないので、本番環境で使うのは非推奨です。HTTPサーバ & WSGI & Python アプリ というのが一般的な構成になります。

Comment: 承知しました！無視いたします！教えていただきありがとうございます。